# What is the difference between /mnt/boot and /boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot, mount, uefi

I'm installing Arch Linux and going by the instructions I want to mount the EFI partition at `/boot`, however I see on the internet people using both `/boot` and `/mnt/boot` and I have no idea what the difference is, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are installing Arch, follow the [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide) *to the letter*. Do not change anything. And don't follow any other guides, don't go to any random YouTube videos or anything, just use the official Arch docs. They are excellent. Once you have installed, you can always make adjustments, but the best way to screw up an Arch install is to deviate in any way from the guide.

Now, while installing Arch, what you do is boot into a simple live system and then you set up the partitions for the actual installation. While in this live system, you are [expected to mount](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide#Mount_the_file_systems) everything under `/mnt`, but that's only while preparing. When you actually boot into your installed system, those things will be mounted in the normal locations.

So while installing, your `/` is mounted to `/mnt` and that's why `/boot` is mounted to `/mnt/boot`.  You will see that in a subsequent step, you are asked to run `arch-chroot /mnt` which mimics having booted into the system whose `/` is `/mnt`. But all this is just for setting up. Once you are done, you will reboot and your `/` will be `/` and `/boot` will be `/boot` and not `/mnt/boot`.

Comment: The "EFI system partition" page referenced in that same installation guide is the one mentioning only `/boot` while the installation guide is mentioning `/mnt/boot`, so following that guide to the letter is obviously the problem. If the official arch docs *were* excellent I wouldn't be asking this question, would I? I also wouldn't need to wait 40 minutes to ask what a `root volume` is, as it is just casually dropped in the install guide and has no definition, anywhere I could find and I have no idea if I need it.

Comment: Root volume is just the root partition, @user107586, nothing special. And yes, [the guide says](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide#Mount_the_file_systems) you mount to `/mnt/boot` _while installing_. And then, after booting the installed system, it will be at `/boot`. When reading the [EFI system partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition) page, you are looking at documentation about an already installed system, so it uses the normal `/boot`. But while installing, and only then, you mount it at `/mnt/boot` because your `/` is actually `/mnt`.

Comment: OK, I understand that now but it in no way is explained in the docs was my point. So, what, then, would be the difference between `/` and `/home`? And is the root partition the partition with all the files you will use as a user or something special?

Comment: @user107586 `/` is the root partition. Kinda like what `C:/` is in Windows. And `/home` is where user directories are. So your user's home directory would be `/home/user107586` (or whatever username you choose).  If this is your first foray into Linux, you might want to consider something other than Arch. Arch is great, it's what I use myself, but it does assume a certain level of experience. If you're new to Linux, I completely understand why you find the documentation confusing, Arch is aimed at more experienced users. It's a great learning experience, but not easy.